# Adding asp.net web application template in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net

I am using visual studio 2010. When I click on New website->  Visual C# -> I have numbers of options except **ASP.Net WebApplication**. How do i get the ASP.Net Web Application option to show up?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `File -> New Project` from `Menu`.
In the `New Project` window, you can see the option to create an `ASP.NET WebApplication`.

You could find the difference between *Web Site* and *Web Application* in the link below:

- **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx**